# How should i store the information of a user

Tags: android, database, kotlin, security, account

I'm developing my first serious project , a fitness app in kotlin using a room database to store all the user related information , and i was wondering if it is safe to store the account information (user email , user hashed password etc) using Room API  instead of saving it in an encrypted file inside internal storage of the app

So far i have implemented the entitity , the repository and integrated it in the on-board process and login process

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_account_table")
data class AccountInformationDTO(

    val encrypted_password:String ="DEFAULT_PASSWORD_ENCRYPTED",
    val email:String = "DEFAULT_EMAIL",
    val firstName:String = "John",
    val lastName:String = "Snow",
    val provider:String = "EMAIL",
    val rememberMe:Boolean = true,
    val termsAgreed:Boolean = true,
    val isEmailVerified:Boolean = false,
    val isRegisteredInFirebase:Boolean = false
    ){
      @PrimaryKey var accountUID:String = "DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_UID"
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to store encrypted user password locally? Is it for something like remembering the user's password to log in automatically? Is there any backend that communicates with your app?

Comment: I want use it to auth the user when there is no internet connection available .

Comment: Offline mode huh? Okay so it should be generally acceptable for a fitness app to store encrypted hashes of passwords, emails and other data in Room as Shaked stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75301610/4153947). It will sit in app's private directory(which is not accessible by other parties without root) and additionally the Android devices are now encrypted by [default](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/264642/are-android-phones-now-encrypted-by-default) so the system encrypts this data.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly Room stores its sqlite files in the app's data dir.
It should be fine for most use cases, but if you want to add more layer of security you should look at Sqlite Cipher to encrypt your data